# twitter API search for tweets

Tags: api, search, twitter

I am trying to get the public tweets from one user to another from over a year ago but I cannot seem to get the search API to work. I have authenticated my application and tested the API so the application is able to use the API. I have read the documentation at:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search and https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets and followed the instruction of how a query should be structured but it still does not return any results. I get the right results when I search using https://twitter.com/search-advanced so why can I not duplicate the results when using the API? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the The Twitter Search API documentation, the query you want is not possible:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets
>   published in the past 7 days.

Beyond the last 7 days, what you want to achieve can only be done through manually searching an account on Twitter. One option would be to use https://webrecorder.io/

Scroll to the time you want to record or attempt to capture the entire feed. Note the auto scrolling option as well.